# xmlToList does not return xmlValue

Tags: xml, r

I have two XML files with essentially the same structure. However, xmlToList does not return the XML value for one of the files. Here is the example that works:

```
library(XML)
doc1 <- xmlParse("http://www.wnba.com/games/game_component/dynamic/20130527/CHIPHO/pbp_all.xml")
node1 <- getNodeSet(doc1, path="/")
l1 <- xmlToList(node1[[1]])
l1[[1]][[1]][[1]]

$text
[1] "<![CDATA[(10:00)Start Period]]>"

$.attrs
eventid         prd  game_clock        htms        vtms    msg_type action_type player_code 
    "1"         "1"     "10:00"         "0"         "0"        "12"         "0"          "" 
     tm 
"mercury"
```

Here is the example that doesn't:

```
doc2 <- xmlParse("http://www.nba.com/games/game_component/dynamic/20130528/MIAIND/pbp_all.xml")
node2 <- getNodeSet(doc2, path="/")
l2 <- xmlToList(node2[[1]])
l2[[1]][[1]][[1]]

[[1]]
NULL

$.attrs
eventid         prd  game_clock        htms        vtms    msg_type action_type player_code 
    "0"         "1"     "12:00"         "0"         "0"        "12"         "0"          "" 
     tm 
"pacers"
```

I would expect to see `(12:00)Start Period` instead of `NULL`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems with the second file:

- `<` and `>` instead of `&lt` and `&gt`
- `>event>` instead of closing tag `</event>` at `eventid="185"`

I've placed the corrected XML for you to pastebin:

```
> doc3 <- xmlParse("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LkwZmqmw")
> node3 <- getNodeSet(doc3, path="/")
> l3 <- xmlToList(node3[[1]])
> l3$message$game[[1]]

$text
[1] "<![CDATA[(12:00)Start Period]]>"

$.attrs
    eventid         prd  game_clock        htms        vtms    msg_type action_type player_code          tm 
        "0"         "1"     "12:00"         "0"         "0"        "12"         "0"          ""    "pacers"
```

Comment: This is great, but it would be even better if I could automatically detect & fix those problems (preferably using R). Any thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out a decent solution and posted [here](https://gist.github.com/cpsievert/8412484)